# url rewrite rule resulting in err_too_many redirects

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect, artifactory

I am using a docker container for artifactory. Within the container the following redirect rule exists [code on github](https://github.com/fkirill/dockerfile-artifactory/blob/master/urlrewrite/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml).Is there anyway to edit to avoid getting the above error? The url is [artifactory.inmz.net](http://artifactory.inmz.net)

```
 <
urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <name>redirect from  / to artifactory url</name>
        <condition name="path-translated" operator="notequal">artifactory</condition>
        <from>^/(.*)$</from>
        <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">/artifactory/$1</to>
    </rule>
```